# Gmail api to get all the accounts that a user has given send as permissions

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to find the users/accounts who can use my gmail id for impersonation using gmail api.

The following api call only gives me the accounts that I can use to 'send as'
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/settings/sendAs

I want other way around, I want to find out the accounts which use my email id as 'send as'

Is there a way to get it using any api ?

Example: suppose a user is using his corporate gmail id to send email from his personal gmail, basically I want to find all the personal gmail ids he is using 'send as'from corporate email

Thank you,
Lisa